# Как очищать консоль?

Tags: python, консоль, таймер

Пытался реализовать секундомер в консоли, но не нашел способа, как очищать консоль, при новой выдаче.
Суть в том, что нужно чтобы значения обновлялись, а не выводились каждый раз на новую строку.
Сам код:

```
import time, os
seconds,minutes,hours = 0,0,0
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes+=1
    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0
        hours+=1
    if hours > 0:
        print(f"{'hours'} : {hours:02}    {'minutes'} : {minutes:02}    {'seconds'} : {seconds:02}")   
    elif minutes > 0:
        print(f"{'minutes'} : {minutes:02}    {'seconds'} : {seconds:02}")
    else: 
        print(f"{'seconds'} : {seconds:02}",sep='',end='\r')
        os.system('cls||clear')
    seconds+=1
```

Пишу на Windows, VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
print(f"\r{'hours'} : {hours:02}    {'minutes'} : {minutes:02}    {'seconds'} : {seconds:02}", end="")
```

Ну и для всех остальных, соответственно. То есть, \r возвращает каретку в начало строки, а end="" не переносит ввод на следующую, то есть, если в обычном print обычно конец вывода сообщения заканчивается \n, то в этом случае переноса не будет.

Ну и в этом случае очищать вывод не нужно, то есть os.system('cls||clear') можно убрать.

Вот результат работы. Как видите, уже досчитало до 8 без переносов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас это работает? У меня не произвело никакого эффекта, как печаталось до этого, с каждой новой строки, так и печатается.

Comment: Работает. Как только показать не знаю. Попробуйте запустить скрипт из командной строки. Посмотрите в ней

Comment: Да, думаю проблема в самой среде разработки, она не позволяет выполнить очистку в терминале. В консоли работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
```

Comment: Так тоже работает, даже без lambda. Тут фишка в том, что в IDE это может не работать. А вот в терминале или командной строке без проблем. Для примера, в PyCharm это не работает. Запускаешь в терминале, все чиститься.

Answer (score 0):

Фантазия на тему:

```py
import time

start = time.monotonic()
while True:
    current = (loop_start := time.monotonic()) - start
    min_total, seconds = divmod(current, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(min_total, 60)

    time_pattern = (
        ('hours {:02}', int(hours), ()),
        ('minutes {:02}', int(minutes), (hours,)),
        ('seconds {:02}', int(seconds), (minutes, hours)),
    )
    time_string = ' '.join(
        map(lambda x: x[0].format(x[1]), filter(lambda x: x[1] or any(x[2]), time_pattern))
    )
    print(
        time_string, end='\r'
    )
    delay = 1 - (time.monotonic() - loop_start) % 1
    
    time.sleep(
        delay
    )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, скоро рванет ))